# Private class method from public class method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class Foo
  def self.bar()
    puts("bar")
  end
  private_class_method :bar

  def self.foo()
    self.bar()
  end
end
```

Given the above example, why does:

```
 > Foo.foo()
NoMethodError: private method `bar' called for Foo:Class
```

instead of:

```
 > Foo.foo()
=> bar
```

I'm trying to create a class/namespce composed of "helper" methods `Thing.helper(...)`, etc...  I would prefer to have the internal methods scoped privately so someone at least has to go out of their way to call them directly.  Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Java equivalent:

```
class Foo {
  private static void bar() {
    System.out.println("bar");
  }
  public static void foo() {
    bar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you try to call your private method with explicit receiver, `self`. Try simply

```
def self.foo
  bar
end
```